# How do I perform server-side rendering (or prerendering) with an existing React app in .NET 7.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, server-side-rendering

How do I perform server-side rendering (or prerendering) with an existing React app in .NET 7.0? The app is already compiled and minimized, and it will hydrate.

I've found [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions#readme-body-tab) but it's poorly documented. I've also found [a Medium article](https://medium.com/@apakmahmud/server-side-rendering-react-with-net-core-1f3eaf8962fb) from 2019 but it seems outdated and dependent on a Babel server.

I want to put in the least amount of effort to evaluate the overall viability of SSR and .NET. I don't need hot reload, bundling (webpack) and recompiling of static assets right now.